# How to check if an array is sorted and rotated clockwise in if it is in decreasing order in Java?

Tags: java

I have to check whether the array is in decreasing order and rotated,
for example: `44 43 11 10 9` is sorted in decreasing order and when we rotate it twice then it will be `10 9 44 43 11`.

I have attached my code but it is not optimal for case of `[43 44 11 10 9]` because in this case the array is not sorted and rotated, because when we sort the array it will be 44 43 11 10 9 and there is no possibilities in terms of rotation that it would be 43 44 11 10 9 , In fact the output should be "No" but in my case output is "Yes". As per my code, I am unable to handle the given case for optimize my code.

```java
class Main {

    public static boolean antiClockRotation(int arr[]) {
        int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        int index = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i] > max) {
                max = arr[i];
                index = i;
            }
        }
        if (index == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        int i = 0;
        int j = 1;
        while (i < index  &&  j < index) {
            if (arr[i] <= arr[j]) {
                return false;
            }
            i++;
            j++;
        }
        int k = index;
        int l = index+1;
        while (k < arr.length - 1  &&  l < arr.length) {
            if (arr[k] <= arr[l]) {
                return false;
            }
            k++;
            l++;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Your code here
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            int size = sc.nextInt();
            int arr[] = new int[size];
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                arr[j] = sc.nextInt();
            }
            if (antiClockRotation(arr)) {
                System.out.println("Yes");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("No");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to achieve the case if the array is sorted and rotated clockwise in decreasing order.

For example : `6 5 4 3 2 1` is the array which is in decreasing order but when we rotate 2 times so it will be `2 1 6 5 4 3` and output should be "Yes".

But in case of `44 43 11 10 9` the array is in decreasing order but in the case of
`(43 44 11 10 9)` it is not rotated so the output should be "No".

Comment: What do you mean by 'rotated clockwise'?  An array can be sorted in either ascending or descending order. But this is not a circle, there is no clockwise or anti-clockwise direction. It is start to end or end to start.

Comment: I've seen the terms "rotate left/right" but never seen "rotate clockwise" unless when referring to 2-dimensional drawings. Also I've never heard of "rotated in descending order" - do you mean "sorted in descending order and THEN rotated"? Please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: clockwise rotation means if the array is 6 5 4 3 2 1 so when we rotate 2 times it will be 2 1 6 5 4 3

Comment: @shanu you’ve received an answer, if that works for you, consider accepting it. People volunteer their time on stackoverflow, and walking away after posting a question is not a good way to appreciate these volunteers.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is track the highest element to the left of the inflection point. For example, 44, 43, 11, 10, 9, every element is smaller that the one on its left, so, answer is yes, but 43, 44, 11, 10, 9, you find 44 greater than 43 (or whatever in general is the greatest on the left). After the inflection point, every element must be smaller than the one on its left, and the last element (9) must be greater than the greatest element on the left of the inflection point (43), so, the answer is no.

**Edit:**

Added code.

```
public static boolean isSortedAndRotated(int arr[]) {
    int n = arr.length;
    if (n <= 1) {
        return true;
    }
    int fst = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        if (arr[i] > arr[i - 1]) {
            if (fst > Integer.MIN_VALUE) {
                return false;
            }
            fst = arr[0];
        }
    }
        
    return arr[n - 1] >= fst;
}
```

Comment: But in case of 6 5 4 3 2 1 if i rotate the array by 1 time so it will be 1 6 5 4 3 2 and in this case the output will be "No" as per your description but expectation is "Yes"

Comment: and 43 44 11 10 9 is neither sorted nor rotated because if it is sorted by 44 43 11 10 9 so there is no any case of rotation  where we will get 43 44 11 10 9

Comment: @shanu you need to read my answer CAREFULLY and try it by hand on paper. Both the use cases you mentioned are covered by my algorithm

Comment: I think I am unable to let u understand ,  you mentioned that "For example, 44, 43, 11, 10, 9, every element is smaller that the one on its left, so, answer is yes, " but I am not looking for only sorted element , However it will be rotated also .. for Example : 44 43 11 10 9 is sorted but once when I rotate them 2 times then it will be 10 9 44 43 11 and in this case there is no more possibilities that every element will be smaller than its left

Comment: @shanu I've written the code for you, you can now copy-paste. Enjoy!

Comment: I've just tested it: https://ideone.com/ccHiA0

Comment: This is a clever algorithm once the reader understands how it works. I had to spend some time thinking about it (and wrote the above program to test it). This will be easier to understand if you define the term "inflection point" as you've used it in your explanation.

Comment: @k314159 “inflection point” is a standard mathematical term. The reader is expected to be aware of it, and even if they aren’t, they can google it. Defining it would be like defining min and max. Still, here it is: “_a point of a curve at which a change in the direction of curvature occurs_”

Comment: In that case I don't think this is the same kind of inflection point that you are talking about. For example, in the sequence 44, 43, 41, 33, 25, 21, 19, 18, all numbers are decreasing but there is an inflection point at 33, because at that point the curve goes from convex to concave as seen from above.